# Ansible with_fileglob - issue with a variable in a path

Tags: ansible

I have a problem when I want to add a variable into a path which is used by `with_fileglob` - it seems that the variable is always expended to "[]".

I ran the playbook with parameter `--extra-vars environment="dev"` and got from debug output `extra_vars: ('environment=dev',)`.

Unfortunatelly copy task with `with_fileglob` failed:

```
 - name: Copy all files from environment subdirectory
    copy:
      src: "{{item}}"
      dest: /etc/
    with_fileglob: directory/{{ environment }}/*


TASK [Copy all files from environment subdirectory] ************************************************************************
task path: /home/ansible/playbook/playbook.yml:511
looking for "files/directory/[]" at "/home/ansible/playbook/files/files/directory/[]"
looking for "files/directory/[]" at "/home/ansible/playbook/files/directory/[]"
looking for "files/directory/[]" at "/home/ansible/playbook/files/files/directory/[]"
looking for "files/directory/[]" at "/home/ansible/playbook/files/directory/[]"
[WARNING]: Unable to find 'files/directory/[]' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)
```

I am using ansible 2.9.3.

May I ask you what I did wrong?
Thanks a lot for your hints in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*environment*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords) is a reserved keyword and can't be used as the name of a variable. See [Creating valid variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names). The fixed variable in the playbook below works as expected

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: item
      with_fileglob: "directory/{{ env }}/*"
```

Given the tree

```sh
shell> tree directory
directory
└── dev
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── file3

1 directory, 3 files
```

the abridged result is

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e "env=dev" | grep item:
  item: /scratch/tmp/directory/dev/file2
  item: /scratch/tmp/directory/dev/file1
  item: /scratch/tmp/directory/dev/file3
```